# Special Relativity: Interpretation of the partial derivate of Stress-Energy Tensor

Tags: special-relativity, conservation-laws, tensor-calculus, definition, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

This question is based on Carroll's book *Spacetime and Geometry*, specifically from page 33 to page 36.

In the upper mentioned section we define the Stress-Energy Tensor as:

> The flux of the four momentum $p^\mu$ across a surface of constant $x^\nu$

Here lies the first problem: canonically the flux of a vector across a surface is a scalar, not a matrix or a tensor. So I don't get this definition at all.

But nevertheless I understand that the Stress-Energy Tensor represent a generalization of the concept of mass and energy, so we can move forward for now. We then get the form of the Stress-Energy Tensor for a *perfect fluid:*
$$T^{\mu\nu}=(\rho+p)U^\mu U^\nu+p\eta^{\mu\nu}$$
(where $\rho$ is the *energy density*, $p$ si the pressure and $U$ is the four-velocity; keep in mind that we are working in flat spacetime). This is fine for me, however then we come to the following expression:
$$\partial _\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$$
It is stated that the $\nu=0$ component corresponds to the **conservation of energy** and the other three components correspond to the **conservation of momentum**; but no direct proof, or justification, of this statement is given. Using the definition of $T^{\mu\nu}$ previously cited: **how can we show that the upper mentioned statement is true, or at least plausible?**

Comment: I don't understand your comment "canonically the flux of a vector across a surface is scalar...".  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux#General_mathematical_definition_(transport)  and compare to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux#Flux_as_a_surface_integral. Are you mixing the two definitions?  For the former, the "scalar" case is a very special case.

Comment: Secondly, this seems like two distinct questions to me.  Really you should ask one question at a time, and the second one, at least, probably has an answer somewhere on this site already.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental tensor equation of relativistic mechanics of continous matter is
$$ K^\mu = \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} $$
where $K^\mu$ is the 4-force-density acting on material medium and  $T^{\mu\nu}$
is the energy-momentum-stress tensor of the system.
Consistently for $\nu=0$ we obtain the equation of continuity and for $\nu=1,2,3$ the 3-vector equation of motion.
Of course, in absence of external forces ($K^\mu=0$), the scalar relation corresponds to conservation of energy and the vector relation becomes the law of conservation of linear momentum.